# Remove button from for all clients Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to remove a button so once it is clicked it will become hidden to the     client who clicked it AND to all other clients connected.  Here is what i have      so far.

```
server side

socket.on('seat1',function(){
       player.x = 380
       player.y = 300
       player.number = 1
       console.log(player)
       socket.emit('hideSeat1')

    });

client side

var seat1 = function(){
        socket.emit('seat1',{

        });

   }

socket.on('hideSeat1',function(){
        document.getElementById('seat1').style.display = "none";
    });
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to auto assign seats when connecting, but i can't figure out how to make that work either.

Comment: What is wrong with the code? I dont see anything wrong....